# I want the nav bar in top right corner

Tags: html, css

I  am creating a blogging website and  designed  a  nav  bar.The nav bar   shows  up  in  the  left  side  and  I  want  it  in  the  top  right  corner..... I have  tried  by  using  `justify-content:right;`  but  it  hasn't  work......  How  to  get the nav bar to the right top corner? Help me out......
Here's the following snippet-

```css
body {
  background-color: #111;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul li a {
  --c: rgb(178, 218, 32);
  color: var(--c);
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 1em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--c);
  transform: translateY(150%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc((var(--n) - 1) * 25%);
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: calc((var(--n) - 1) * 0.1s);
  z-index: -1;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

ul li a:hover span {
  transform: translateY(0) scale(2);
}

ul li a span:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

ul li a span:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

ul li a span:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

ul li a span:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">home <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">service <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">about <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">contact <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add `justify-content: flex-end` to `ul { ... }`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: used span for adding bubble which can give a  hover effect in nav bar @mplungjan

Comment: Does `float: right;` work?

Comment: @mplungjan, This is a very simple solution, and it seems to me there are duplicates of this question.

Comment: It worked..Thank you @s.kuznetsov

Comment: @ParshwaLahkar, no problem.